# HTML textarea not correctly sized in table in ie8. Doctype problem?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, textarea, doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">       
        #textarea1 {
            width: 100%;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        #table1 {
    background-color:#0000ff;
    width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <table id="table1" >
        <tr><td><textarea  cols="0" rows="2" id="textarea1"></textarea></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The textarea is not rendered correctly by ie8 in the table (it is wider than its cell).
If I remove the doctype tag it renders correctly. Am I doing something stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE, for some reason, interprets 100% width of a table cell as 100px-(padding/2), inherited from your #table1 width property.
Now here's where it really screws up: the table has a default cellspacing of 3 pixels, so technically, your cell should be 94px wide, and 100% of that width should be... 94px.  Instead, it's applying 100px.

If you explicitly set the width property of the table cell, it can correct it, but only after you set the `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` to `0`, and the `border-width` of the textarea to `0`.

e.g.:

```
#textarea1 {
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
}
#table1 {
background-color:#0000ff;
width: 100px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
border-spacing:0;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
#table1 td {
width:100px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

The alternative, if you want normal borders around your textarea, is to define a `width` for the `td` as `100px - border-wdith*2`.

Hope that helps,
nd

Comment: Forgot to mention: Use a reset stylesheet.  Solves a lot of problems like the one you're experiencing here with applied margins and padding.

Comment: Thanks for this, thought it wasn't entirely my fault. Isn't this a rather basic thing for a browser to get wrong?

Comment: Absolutely.  Internet Explorer's interpretation of the Box Model has been pretty poor, but it appears to be getting better with each new release.

Answer (score 0):

`cols="0"` seems a bit daft. Set that to a sensible value for users without CSS.

You might want to try removing borders and padding from the `textarea`:

```
#textarea1 {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0;
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

`width` refers to the width of the element’s content area, i.e. the area inside the margin, borders and padding

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if you're using <asp:textbox> control, with attributes runat="server" and TextMode="MultiLine", it works fine. 
And if you view the source - strange enough - what you get is a html textarea just as you would have defined it (I could not find any differences between the asp rendering and a straight-forward html definition of a textbox within a table).

If you have asp.net anyway, you can use it easily that way, it renders nicely. All you have to do is to put the prefix "ctl00_MainContent_" before the ID (or whatever ASP.NET renders in your case depending on the surroundings) - just look it up once via "view source" in IE or with the developer toolbar.

So in jQuery, a

> $('#ctl00_MainContent_myTextbox').val()

would retrieve the value, if

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextbox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" style="height:50px; width:90%"></asp:TextBox>
```

is defined in your code. You can put the prefix '#ctl00_MainContent_' in a variable for your convenience, e.g.:

```
var aspPrefix='#ctl00_MainContent_'; // global variable
var textValue = $(aspPrefix+'myTextbox').val(); // example to get value
```

Everything else works as you would expect it.